# Movement is dependent to frame-rate. How can i make it independent from frame-rate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

i am pretty new to coding. till now i searched lots of things yet i still couldn't solve my problem. I am trying to make a gameObject follow a line/graph. i tried to give him a negative-Y velocity and adding small numbers(something like; update{mybody.velocity += 0.005}) each update to make it move. but i encountered a problem which is at low frame-rate my object is taking a super wide path and at higher frame-rate it take super tight path. how can i make my movement independent.

```
private float curve = 0;
private float curvemax = 2.3f;
[SerializeField]
private float curveupdate = 0.05f;
if (tracking.found && !hareketeBaşlandı)
        {
            curve = -(curvemax);
            triggered1 = true;
            hareketeBaşlandı = true;
            print(curve);

        }
        if (transform.position.y != y1-curvemax && tracking.found)
        {
            curve += curveupdate;

            print(curve+"Curving");
            
        }
        
        if (curve >= (curvemax))
        {

            curve = 0;
            y2 = transform.position.y;
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, y1, transform.position.z);
            tracking.found = false;
            tracking.shouldsearch = false;
            StartCoroutine("trackCD");
            print("track off");
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(myBody.velocity.x, curve);
            hareketeBaşlandı = false;

        }
```

Comment: I don't work much with Unity but `Time.deltaTime` might be what you're looking for?

Comment: i am almost certain i can solve it with keyword Time, i tried to use Time.deltaTime but it seems i can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking about "rate of change," you must think about "rate of change *per unit of time*".

For example, you seem to be updating `curve` based on `curveupdate = 0.05f;`, which has a rate of change of `0.05f`. You need to be thinking about how much rate of change *per second*. Assuming you currently get `0.05f` change per frame, and let's say 10 frames per second, that means your rate of change per second is `0.5f` (ten times higher) per second.

You then apply this amount multiplied by the number of seconds elapsed. Here's how to do it.

First when you kick off the animation, you need to remember when it started:

```
var lastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Then change this:

```
curve += curveupdate;
```

To this:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
float secondsElapsed = (float)(currentTime - lastUpdateTime).TotalMilliseconds / 1000F;
curve += (curveupdate * secondsElaped);
lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
```

This way, the amount of change scales depending on how much time has passed. If no time has passed, it will scale all the way down to 0, and if hours have passed, it will end up very very large. To an end user, the rate of change should seem consistent over time as a result.

Comment: This is completely wrong in Unity.  There is - obviously - a way to do this in Unity, since - obviously - that is the entire point of a frame-based game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using `DateTime.Now` and `TimeSpan` calculations as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67441972/7111561) are quite expensive ... especially if you use it **every frame** just to calculate a delta in seconds.

This is actually exactly what Unity already provides in [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) the time in seconds passed since last few was rendered .. so why calculate it complicated if we already know the value ;)

```
curve += curveupdate * Time.deltaTime;
```

In simple words multiplication by `Time.deltaTime` converts any value from "value per frame" into a frame-rate independent "value per second"